# How can I set default the background slideshow settings?

Tags: shotwell, slideshow

I set up a slideshow with Shotwell. Then I wanna change the time interval between two images but there is no setting in Shotwell about that. So I create a new one.
The problem started here. The last slideshow is not affected by new settings. The old one is still working. How can I set default the slideshow settings in Ubuntu?

Comment: what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @PRATAP last version i just downloaded yesterday 18.04LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the default values by below commands

```
gsettings get org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.slideshow delay
gsettings get org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.slideshow show-title
gsettings get org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.slideshow transition-delay
```

Example:

```
pratap@i7-4770:~$ gsettings get org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.slideshow delay
3.0
pratap@i7-4770:~$ gsettings get org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.slideshow show-title
false
pratap@i7-4770:~$ gsettings get org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.slideshow transition-delay
0.29999999999999999
```

now set your preferred values by below commands

```
gsettings set org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.slideshow delay 1
gsettings set org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.slideshow show-title true
gsettings set org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.slideshow transition-delay 0.1
```

Example:

```
pratap@i7-4770:~$ gsettings set org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.slideshow delay 1
pratap@i7-4770:~$ gsettings set org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.slideshow show-title true
pratap@i7-4770:~$ gsettings set org.yorba.shotwell.preferences.slideshow transition-delay 0.1
pratap@i7-4770:~$
```

[image]

***Alternatively*** you can install `dconf-editor` with below command

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Once, Installed Open it and search for `shotwell`
you can see lot of options if you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice, if you observe the animation I attached, there are left arrow pause right arrow settings button.. from this settings button also we can change the settings but it's not working in 18.04.. Working in 18.10